# Do aeroshells need to be super smooth to survive atmospheric entry?

Tags: reentry, heat-shield, aerobraking

IIRC, one of the arguments against Shuttle Columbia's hole being repaired was that the repair would not be smooth. Apparently, the heat shielding relied on a sensitive boundary layer. Even a small bump could increase the tempertures around 600 degrees Celcius. Is this true? If so, does it apply to other spacecraft (eg; capsules, rover aeroshells, the Starship, etc) What are the tolerances and the potential temperature rise from defects?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://youtu.be/roNMWE2CJxk

Comment: Slide 61-64 of the [Aerothermodynamics Holy Grail](https://tfaws.nasa.gov/TFAWS12/Proceedings/Aerothermodynamics%20Course.pdf) discusses turbulent heating